# Simulating C++ code with Azure Digital Twins

Tags: c++, azure, azure-digital-twins

I am trying to do a project that takes values from a physical device and compares it to the values of from a Digital Twin, for this I have a physical device and a C++ representation of the model that I want to compare.

I already set up a connection for my real data to get to Azure IoT hub and then via Azure Function over to the Azure Digital Twin but now I'm a bit stuck what is the best option to run the virtual simulation to create my virtual data and compare it.

Any ideas what is the optimal way to run C++ code virtually in the Azure environment?

Answer (score 1):

Azure functions does not support C++ code support out of the box. Please refer to the resource [Language support details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/supported-languages#language-support-details) to get more information on supported languages. You can look into creating [Azure custom handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-custom-handlers) and figure out a way create a custom handler to support C++ code.

If you can off load the Comparisions from Cloud to different device, [Azure IoT Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/?view=iotedge-1.4) is a great way to achieve the same functionality. With this approach you are not limited with programming choice and IoT Edge supports [Creation of Custom modules in C++](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-v1/issues/383). Azure IoT Edge has support for Windows and Linux environments where you can build custom modules and can send the processed filtered result to the Azure IoT Hub. Azure IoT Edge can also be set up on devices such as Raspberry Pi.

If your actual device supports Azure IoT Edge, the best way to achieve the use case is to get the C++ representation of the model on to the edge module and compare it with the data and pass the processed data to the Azure IoT Hub.

Here are a couple of resources that will help you get started with Azure IoT Edge

1. [Deploy your first IoT Edge module to a virtual Linux device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart-linux?view=iotedge-1.4)
2. [Develop a C IoT Edge module using Linux containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-c-module?view=iotedge-1.4)